# Image classification with zero data

Tags: machine-learning, image-processing, classification

Given an image of a biology diagram, I would like to classify the diagram into these 4 categories:

1. Plant
2. Animal
3. Cell
4. Anatomy

However, I don't have any training data. I would like to avoid the crowdsourcing for data. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Probably you're out of luck.  But for this to be answerable: Please give example pictures for each category.  Please tell us what approaches you have considered.  Why does the title say "text" but the body say "image"?

Comment: @D.W. I was also a little confused by the title saying "text" AND there being the NLP tag. I understood the question is really about images, so I removed the NLP tag. Hopefully the OP can clarify too.